# Windows10 - DBGView-Sysinternals outputs from various Windows-Tasks

Tags: windows-10, debug, sysinternals

I´ve got a Laptop (HP ProBook 4720s) with Windows 10 running.

For work we use DBGView from sysinternals too catch outputs from our self writen programs in order too find hard to find errors / bugs and general outputs. 
This works fine in general, but for a few years I find strange outputs from my system in DBGView, a lot of errors and stuff I myself cant really debug any further alone.

Generally I can add a filter for something like ".cpp" and I get rid of most of them and I can continue my work, but errors are errors and I don´t feel to comfortable having them!

I allready tracked it down and had some wild guesses but I cant recreate errors on another machine, so I´m stuck at beginning. Maybe someone here in can help me get some ideas what to do..

The whole DBGView-Output from 3 Minutes Session is available here: http://pastebin.com/G48N9atD

to get things started a small sample:

> SystemSettingsBroker.exe  SystemSettingsBroker.exe    1320        3.420 K 15.980 K    System Settings Broker  Microsoft Corporation   Microsoft Corporation

```
[1320] shell\systemsettingsthreshold\handlers\internal\display\lib\display.cpp(2461)\SettingsHandlers_nt.dll!00007FFDD91361D8: (caller: 00007FFDD91310A2) Exception(730) tid(e30) 80070002 Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
```

> explorer.exe  explorer.exe    8684    0.25    107.628 K   143.532 K   Windows-Explorer    Microsoft Corporation

```
[8684] shell\explorer\taskband2\taskband2.cpp(4148)\Explorer.EXE!00007FF622E47C4A: (caller: 00007FFE12277DE3) ReturnHr(703) tid(1404) 80004005 Unbekannter Fehler
```

Happens everytime I open a .txt-File no matter if with Notepad, PsPad oder Notepad++

> smartscreen.exe   smartscreen.exe 4236        8.372 K 14.820 K    SmartScreen Microsoft Corporation

```
[4236] ds\security\smartscreen\common\core\src\script_host.cpp(51)\smartscreen.exe!00007FF6FDCC5697: (caller: 00007FF6FDCC5DD8) Exception(3) tid(22b4) 80070001 Unzulässige Funktion. 
[4236]     Msg:[Unable to get property 'substr' of undefined or null reference - TypeError: Unable to get property 'substr' of undefined or null reference
[4236]    at ShellCallbacks.isFileSupported (Unknown script code:1:2413)
[4236]    at ShellCallbacks.prototype.getSamplingRate (Unknown script code:1:2988)
[4236]    at Anonymous function (Unknown script code:1:925)
[4236]    at Array.prototype.reduce (native code)
[4236]    at CallbacksBase.prototype.getSamplingRates (Unknown script code:1:900)
[4236]    at CallbacksBase.prototype.filterEvents (Unknown script code:1:2036)
[4236]    at filterEvents (Unknown script code:1:43)
[4236]    at _dispatch (Unknown script code:13:21)]
```

Unknown to me?!

```
[3028] shell\ext\inputswitch\switch\ctfhandler.cpp(1979)\InputSwitch.dll!00007FFE07D9391D: (caller: 00007FFE07DBB551) LogHr(1) tid(1d68) 80004005 Unbekannter Fehler
```

> explorer.exe  explorer.exe    8684    0.25    107.628 K   143.532 K   Windows-Explorer    Microsoft Corporation

```
[8684] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FFDF47CF210: (caller: 00007FFDF47F24FA) ReturnHr(143) tid(2790) 80070057 Falscher Parameter.
```

> RuntimeBroker.exe RuntimeBroker.exe   3768        10.784 K    33.248 K    Runtime Broker  Microsoft Corporation

```
[3768] onecoreuap\shell\searchfolder\resultsetfactory.cpp(9689)\Windows.Storage.Search.dll!00007FFE0703B7AF: (caller: 00007FFE0EFA3A2B) ReturnHr(1) tid(b54) 80004005 Unbekannter Fehler 
[3768]     CallContext:[\CResultSetFactory::CreateResultSets]
```

> explorer.exe  explorer.exe    6084    0.03    25.240 K    62.432 K    Windows-Explorer    Microsoft Corporation

```
[6084] shell\explorer\traysearchhelper.h(65)\Explorer.exe!00007FF622E9AC70: (caller: 00007FF622E9AA86) ReturnHr(1) tid(1e6c) 8000FFFF Schwerwiegender Fehler
```

> sihost.exe    sihost.exe  9008        5.408 K 21.864 K    Shell Infrastructure Host   Microsoft Corporation

```
[9008] onecoreuap\base\appmodel\execmodel\modern\lifetimemanager\plmdata.cpp(970)\modernexecserver.dll!00007FFDFF6F86C6: (caller: 00007FFDFF7414A0) ReturnHr(54) tid(184c) 8002802B Element nicht gefunden.
```

> svchost.exe   svchost.exe 840 0.01    8.964 K 13.764 K    Hostprozess für Windows-Dienste Microsoft Corporation

```
[840] onecore\base\appmodel\resourcepolicy\gameconfigstore\server\gameconfigstoreserver.cpp(535)\resourcepolicyserver.dll!00007FFE0D5865EB: (caller: 00007FFE0D589C7B) LogHr(1773) tid(22c8) 80070002 Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
```

> ShellExperienceHost.exe   ShellExperienceHost.exe 7440    Suspended   29.152 K    36.948 K    Windows Shell Experience Host   Microsoft Corporation

```
[7440] StartUI.SplitViewFrame
[840] onecore\base\appmodel\resourcepolicy\gameconfigstore\server\gameconfigstoreserver.cpp(535)\resourcepolicyserver.dll!00007FFE0D5865EB: (caller: 00007FFE0D589C7B) LogHr(1778) tid(a98) 80070002 Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden. 
[840] onecore\base\appmodel\resourcepolicy\gameconfigstore\server\gameconfigstoreserver.cpp(1999)\resourcepolicyserver.dll!00007FFE0D589C9D: (caller: 00007FFE0D5892AC) LogHr(1779) tid(a98) 80070002 Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden. 
[840] onecore\base\appmodel\resourcepolicy\gameconfigstore\server\gameconfigstoreserver.cpp(535)\resourcepolicyserver.dll!00007FFE0D5865EB: (caller: 00007FFE0D586C51) LogHr(1780) tid(a98) 80070002 Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden. 
[840] onecore\base\appmodel\resourcepolicy\gameconfigstore\server\gameconfigstoreserver.cpp(2150)\resourcepolicyserver.dll!00007FFE0D58A246: (caller: 00007FFE0D5892BD) LogHr(1781) tid(a98) 80070002 Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden. 
[840] onecore\base\appmodel\resourcepolicy\gameconfigstore\server\gameconfigstorerpcserver.cpp(325)\resourcepolicyserver.dll!00007FFE0D5840A6: (caller: 00007FFE12277DE3) LogHr(1782) tid(a98) 80070002 Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden. 
[6084] shell\lib\logontasks\logontasks.cpp(3736)\Explorer.exe!00007FF622ED6E2C: (caller: 00007FF622E53A6E) LogHr(2) tid(21e8) 8007054F Interner Fehler. 
[6084]     CallContext:[\RunBeforePostStartTasks] 
[6084] onecoreuap\net\netprofiles\winrt\networkinformation\lib\handlemanager.cpp(146)\Windows.Networking.Connectivity.dll!00007FFDF64CA333: (caller: 00007FFDF64C9467) ReturnHr(1) tid(272c) 80070426 Der Dienst wurde nicht gestartet. 
[6084] onecoreuap\net\netprofiles\winrt\networkinformation\lib\handlemanager.cpp(146)\Windows.Networking.Connectivity.dll!00007FFDF64CA333: (caller: 00007FFDF64C9467) ReturnHr(2) tid(272c) 80070426 Der Dienst wurde nicht gestartet. 
[6084] shell\explorer\trayimmersiveshellproxy.cpp(59)\Explorer.exe!00007FF622EF95F6: (caller: 00007FF622E68127) ReturnHr(20) tid(1e6c) 80040155 Schnittstelle nicht registriert 
[6084] shell\explorer\tray.cpp(7020)\Explorer.exe!00007FF622EDD335: (caller: 00007FF622E8FE07) LogHr(3) tid(1e6c) 80040155 Schnittstelle nicht registriert 
[6084] shell\explorer\traysearchhelper.h(80)\Explorer.exe!00007FF622E9AB66: (caller: 00007FF622E9C603) ReturnHr(21) tid(1e6c) 80070490 Element nicht gefunden. 
[6084] shell\explorer\searchbutton.cpp(236)\Explorer.exe!00007FF622E9C622: (caller: 00007FF622E664A1) ReturnHr(22) tid(1e6c) 80070490 Element nicht gefunden. 
[7440] Suspending
```

> svchost.exe   svchost.exe 2380        6.360 K 13.192 K    Hostprozess für Windows-Dienste Microsoft Corporation

```
[2380] onecore\base\appmodel\staterepository\winrt\client\lib\windows.internal.staterepository.tiledatalayer.appinfofactory.cpp(119)\windows.staterepository.dll!00007FFDFFD352C1: (caller: 00007FFE12277DE3) LogHr(98) tid(1718) 80070490 Element nicht gefunden.
```

Answer (score 2):

That are debug outputs from Microsoft tools via [OutputDebugString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/aa363362(v=vs.85).aspx) calls, like you do with your tools.

Ignore the warnings or submit them via Feedback Hub.

Answer (score 0):

DebugView lists the output from all processes, not just yours. You've just been in luck that this has not caused you any issues until now.

To aid you, DebugView displays the process ID (PID), but, unfortunately there is no process filter, but the good news is that the built-in find will search the process ID field as part of a search. As such, one option is to search for the process ID enclosed in square brackets, as this is how they are displayed and this format will reduce the likelihood of picking up the number in some other string. You can then use next and previous to navigate between the various lines for your process.

Note that the keyboard shortcuts for next and previous are a bit weird with F3 jumping to the next or previous depending on your current direction. To toggle direction, you use Shift + F3 once, and then keep on moving in that direction with F3.

An alternative to using find is to save the output or auto-save it using the log feature and then open this file in a text editor and filter the lines using the process ID.

Note that the process ID will change each time you restart your application, so you need to remember to change your find/filter string accordingly.